# Unable to find the recursive solution for coin change

Tags: c++, recursion, dynamic-programming

I was trying to solve the famous coin change problem using recursion. The problem states that you have got a bunch of coins and a target and you have to find the total no of ways the coins can add up to the target. Each coin can be used infinite no of times. This is the solution I found:

```
long int solve(int i,vector<int> coins,int target) {
    if(target==0) {
        return 1;
    }
    if(target<0)
        return 0;      
    if(i<=0) 
        return 0;

    return solve(i-1,coins,target) + solve(i,coins,target-coins[i]);
}
```

Take coins = {1,2,5} and target = 11 for instance. There are 3 ways to represent 11. This code gives an output of 1. I've tried to change the base case by using:

```
if(i==0) 
    return (target%coins[0]==0);
```

The output didn't change.

Comment: c has no `vector<int>`. Please do not spam unrelated tags

Comment: solve has 3 parameters, but you call it with 4. This code wont compile

Comment: why are there 3 ways to represent 11 ??  `2x5 + 1x1`, `11x1`,  `9x1 + 1x2`, `7x1 + 2x2`, I could continue, but its certainly more than 3

Comment: Any combination of 2 coins and 5 coins that adds to at most 11 is a distinct way to represent 11 (we just fill up the remainder with 1 coins). That's 11 > 3: `(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1), (3, 0), (3, 1), (4, 0), (5, 0)`

Comment: You never use `coins[0]` (i.e. 1), so the only possibility is 5+2+2+2. And if `coins[0]` is 1, `target%coins[0]==0` is always true (i.e. 1).

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is using the `std::vector<int>` to store the coin counts and avoid getting the same solution multiple times using a `std::set` keeping track of valid solutions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

const int target = 11;
const vector<int> coins = {1, 2, 5};
set<vector<int>> solutions;

void findSolution(int target, int current, vector<int> usedCoins)
{
    if (current < target) // recursion
    {
        for (int i=0; i<coins.size(); ++i)
        {
            auto newCoins = usedCoins;
            newCoins[i]++;
            findSolution(target, current+coins[i], newCoins);
        }
    }
    else if (current == target) // it's a match
    {
        solutions.insert(usedCoins);
    }
    // else overshoot (currentSum > target) -> do nothing
}

int main()
{
    findSolution(target, 0, vector<int>(coins.size(), 0));
    cout << target << "$ =" << endl;
    for (auto s: solutions)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<s.size(); ++i)
        {   
            count+=s[i];
            cout << s[i] << " x " << coins[i] << "$, ";
        }
        cout << "using " << count << " coins in total." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

gives

```
11$ =
0 x 1$, 3 x 2$, 1 x 5$, using 4 coins in total.
1 x 1$, 0 x 2$, 2 x 5$, using 3 coins in total.
1 x 1$, 5 x 2$, 0 x 5$, using 6 coins in total.
2 x 1$, 2 x 2$, 1 x 5$, using 5 coins in total.
3 x 1$, 4 x 2$, 0 x 5$, using 7 coins in total.
4 x 1$, 1 x 2$, 1 x 5$, using 6 coins in total.
5 x 1$, 3 x 2$, 0 x 5$, using 8 coins in total.
6 x 1$, 0 x 2$, 1 x 5$, using 7 coins in total.
7 x 1$, 2 x 2$, 0 x 5$, using 9 coins in total.
9 x 1$, 1 x 2$, 0 x 5$, using 10 coins in total.
11 x 1$, 0 x 2$, 0 x 5$, using 11 coins in total.
```

for the example of your three possible coins and the target of 11.

Comment: OP: " There are 3 ways to represent 11" your code: 11 different ways

Comment: See @fabians comment. I think there are >3 possible ways. If it is only three, please clarify what is the expected result.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number You did point that out in a comment to the OP as well.

Comment: yes I know, but OP didnt clarify or change the question. The quesiton is asking for "3 ways to represent 11" your code isnt doing that

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number OK, just take the first three solutions then :)

Comment: I think I understood where the 3 comes from. The original exercise on leetCode [https://leetcode.com/problems/coin-change/] asking for the minimum number of coins. I edited my answer to include this, I'll leave it to the OP pick the minimum.